# I want a correct way to Install OSMnx on my fresh Linux

Tags: python, linux-kernel, geopandas, osmnx

I have been installing and using OSMnx on my windows+ anaconda system. But, due to on and on issues on windows I have switched to Linux which is totally fresh.
I need a correct way to install OSMnx on Linux using `pip` . I can't install anaconda due to an
issue with size.

I tried finding .whl files which could help but can't get anywhere some places it mentioned .whl don't work on ubuntu.

I have jupyter notebook installed.
and I want to install OSMnx with proper steps.

Whether, I need to install shapely, fiona or geopandas or `libdev` files.

Please provide me proper steps for it. Thanks

Comment: If installation size is an issue, you could just use miniconda.

Comment: I want without miniconda. I have tried that as well but I was wondering if there’s a way only using pip that’s what the question says

Answer (score 0):

> I can't install anaconda due to an issue with size.

If a size issue is your only problem with anaconda, then you could use miniconda instead, as this will be far easier than installing with pip.

> I need a correct way to install OSMnx on Linux using pip .

The anaconda size issue is the only challenge you stated in your question. *Can* you install with pip? Yes. *Should* you install with pip if a size issue is the only problem? No. But if you truly *need* to install with pip for some other unstated reason, note what the OSMnx [installation instructions](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#installation) state:

> you can install OSMnx via pip if you already have all of its dependencies installed and fully tested on your system. Note: installing the dependencies with pip is nontrivial. If you don’t know exactly what you’re doing, just use conda as described above.

OSMnx is pure Python but several of its dependencies have C/C++ dependencies themselves which must be compiled or must have platform-specific binaries installed. Because of that complexity, the OSMnx project itself formally supports only conda installation. If you *need* to install with pip, you'll need to install OSMnx's required [dependencies](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx/blob/main/requirements.txt) one at a time by going to their developers' home pages and following each of their respective installation instructions for your platform, including installing any of their dependencies as needed. Once everything is installed and tested according to those developers' instructions, you can install OSMnx with pip.

Comment: Alright. I really appreciate and thank you for your time. I shall follow doing it with conda